# Prevent external hard drive from sleeping Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, sleep

I have Windows 10 Pro on MS Surface go 2.

The external HDD is connected with USB3.0 hub.

All works fine, but once the HDD is for like 10 sec inactive, it's going to sleep right away.

I haven't found anything suitable in power settings of Windows.

How I can fix that please ? I'm suspicious that the external USB hub is doing that, but it can of course also be caused by system.

Thank you

Comment: It's probably caused by the drive itself as some have a somewhat annoying power saving feature.

Comment: unfortunatelly, it's doing on all drives I plug in. This one, which I care most, even has external power